# Cannot instantiate class org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SureFireBooterForkException

Tags: java, selenium, maven, jenkins

Is there someone who can provide an insight or clue of what it's causing this error?

From the past three weeks my teammates and I were trying to execute a vanilla Selenium test finding an issue with execution permission from the webdrivers in the server’s side. Once I found a JAVA method to grant permissions to them, the test passed successfully.

Here it’s the code of the JenkinsTest:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;

public class JenkinsTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    String url = "LOGIN_TEST_URL";
    String WebDriverPATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/browserdrivers/geckodriver";

    @BeforeTest
    public void testSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", WebDriverPATH);
        final File file = new File(WebDriverPATH);
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
        firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[formcontrolname='username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[formcontrolname='password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-block")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), url + "URL_TO_COMPARE");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() { driver.close(); }
}
```

With this done, we move on by extending a class called BrowserTest that handles the webdrivers execution and other behaviors:

```java
package com.common;

import java.io.File;
import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.*;

public class BrowserTest {
    protected WebDriver driver;
    protected ResourceBundle configProperties;
    static String rootURL;
    static String WebDriverPATH;

    public static final int CHROME_DRIVER=1;
    public static final int FIREFOX_DRIVER=2;

    protected static Wait<WebDriver> wait;

    public BrowserTest(){ browserSetup(FIREFOX_DRIVER, 5); }

    public BrowserTest(int driverType, int pageTimeout){
        browserSetup(driverType, pageTimeout);
    }    

    private void browserSetup(int driverType, int pageTimeout){
        configProperties = ResourceBundle.getBundle("config");
        rootURL = configProperties.getString(System.getProperty("environment"));
        WebDriverPATH = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        final File file = new File(WebDriverPATH);
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);

        switch (driverType){
            case CHROME_DRIVER:
                String Chrome = WebDriverPATH + "/browserdrivers/chromedriver";
                System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Chrome);
                ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
                options.addArguments("--headless", "--disable-gpu", "--window-size=1920,1200", "--ignore-certificate-errors");
                driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
                break;
            case FIREFOX_DRIVER:
                String Firefox = WebDriverPATH + "/browserdrivers/geckodriver";
                System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", Firefox);
                FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
                FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
                firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
                firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);
                driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
                break;
        }

        wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(45)).pollingEvery(Duration.ofSeconds(3)).ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();    
        driver.navigate().to(rootURL);
    }

    public static void waitForElement(WebElement e){ wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(e)); }

    public void implicitWait(int seconds){
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(seconds,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }    

    public void closeDriver() {
        if(driver != null)
            driver.quit();
    }    

    public void navigateTo(String url){
        driver.navigate().to(rootURL+url);
    }
}
```

Here it is the test extending the class:

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import java.io.File;

public class JenkinsTest {
    WebDriver driver;
    String url = "LOGIN_TEST_URL";
    String WebDriverPATH = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/browserdrivers/geckodriver";

    @BeforeTest
    public void testSetup() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", WebDriverPATH);
        final File file = new File(WebDriverPATH);
        file.setReadable(true, false);
        file.setExecutable(true, false);
        FirefoxBinary firefoxBinary = new FirefoxBinary();
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setBinary(firefoxBinary);
        firefoxOptions.setHeadless(true);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get(url);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() throws InterruptedException {
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[formcontrolname='username")).sendKeys("username");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[formcontrolname='password']")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("button.btn-block")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        Assert.assertEquals(driver.getCurrentUrl(), url + "URL_TO_COMPARE");
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() { driver.close(); }
}
```

Unfortunately we are trying to figure it out why we are getting the following message: There was an error in the forked process Cannot instantiate during the execution of my test on a Jenkins – Maven Project. This is the console output:

```
<===[JENKINS REMOTING CAPACITY]===>channel started
Executing Maven:  -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/pom.xml -Dtest=JenkinsTest test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] ------------------< org.example:qa-playground-test >-------------------
[INFO] Building qa-playground-test 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ qa-playground-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ qa-playground-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 4 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ qa-playground-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ qa-playground-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/target/test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:3.0.0-M4:test (default-test) @ qa-playground-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running JenkinsTest
[ERROR] 
Cannot instantiate class JenkinsTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[ERROR] There are test failures.

Please refer to /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/target/surefire-reports for the individual test results.
Please refer to dump files (if any exist) [date].dump, [date]-jvmRun[N].dump and [date].dumpstream.
There was an error in the forked process
Cannot instantiate class JenkinsTest
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException: There was an error in the forked process
Cannot instantiate class JenkinsTest
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.fork(ForkStarter.java:675)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:285)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.booterclient.ForkStarter.run(ForkStarter.java:248)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeProvider(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1217)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:1063)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:889)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch(Maven35Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

[JENKINS] Recording test results
hudson.AbortException: Test reports were found but none of them are new. Did leafNodes run? 
For example, /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/target/surefire-reports/TEST-JenkinsTest.xml is 2 hr 9 min old

    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:266)
    at hudson.tasks.junit.TestResult.parse(TestResult.java:231)
    at hudson.maven.reporters.SurefireArchiver.postExecute(SurefireArchiver.java:143)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.recordMojoEnded(Maven3Builder.java:619)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$MavenExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(Maven3Builder.java:600)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder$JenkinsEventSpy.onEvent(Maven3Builder.java:303)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyDispatcher.onEvent(EventSpyDispatcher.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.eventspy.internal.EventSpyExecutionListener.mojoSucceeded(EventSpyExecutionListener.java:131)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:87)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.fire(DefaultExecutionEventCatapult.java:42)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:218)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven35Launcher.main(Maven35Launcher.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:225)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven35Main.launch(Maven35Main.java:178)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:139)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:70)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:211)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:54)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:369)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.986 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-06-03T03:09:39Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/QA-Playground/pom.xml to org.example/qa-playground-test/1.0-SNAPSHOT/qa-playground-test-1.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
channel stopped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

**Jenkins server:**

- OS: *Amazon Linux release 2 (Karoo)*
- JDK: *JDK Runtime Environment 1.8.0_242*
- Maven: *3.6.3*

**Project settings:**

- Build section:
- Root POM: *pom.xml*
- Goals and options: *-Dtest=JenkinsTest test*

Finally, this is my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>ARTIFACT-ID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testFailureIgnore>true</testFailureIgnore>
                    <environmentVariables>
                        <DISPLAY>99</DISPLAY>
                    </environmentVariables>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.141.59</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>6.14.3</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
            <artifactId>surefire-booter</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Let me know if you need further information. Thanks in advance and stay safe.

Comment: BTW, sorry for many links for the screenshots but I'm nooby here and I'm not available to add them so this is the only way the platform let me include them. I also got issues with the pom.xml file so I added it as an image.

Sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: First always add files in the post not as images easier to read (also some of us are not allowed to access other sites than SO.. I suppose that starting the browser is going wrong..

Comment: try setting fully-qualified class name as `-Dtest` value

Comment: btw what if you run the build from your local command line? Does it show the same error?

Comment: @AlexeyR. the goal and options on the build section is -Dtest=JenkinsTest test. Do I just need to set it as -Dtest?

Comment: @AlexeyR. about your second comment about run the build from my local command line? Do you mean to execute the -Dtest=JenkinsTest test directly on my jenkins server? I mean, execute it via linux shell? FYI, I'm nooby with Jenkins so sorry if my questions sounds stupid xD

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for the feedback. I edited my post. I supposed I couldn't attached the code of the pom.xml file because the editor had a glitch. Well, I hope the information I provided will be helpful this time.

Comment: First I would suggest to add `<trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>` in your configuration of maven-surefire-plugin. Remove the dependency to `surefire-booter` cause it's done automatically by maven-surefire-plugin itself. Furthermore: Are you really using Maven  3.0.5? Please: I strongly recommend to upgrade to the most recent version 3.6.3 (after you have fixed the testing issue)...Also cleanup the WARNING about the encoding...

Comment: Thanks the feedback, @khmarbaise. I made the update on my pom.xml with your notes and the only difference on the Console Output is the WARNING cleanup. However, I'm still getting the same results.

Comment: About the maven version, on Global Tool the version is 3.6.3 but the other one (3.0.5) I got it by checking it directly on the server:

`[root@ /]# mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.0.5 (Red Hat 3.0.5-17)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_242, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.242.b08-0.amzn2.0.1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.14.173-137.229.amzn2.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
`